# Creating Mobile app with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i need to know that weather i can create a mobile app using ASP.NET MVC4 framework. My concern is not about mobile sites rather apps that can be installed on iphone/android and also can be uploaded to apple store. 
If yes then please suggest some reference links to achieve the same.

Thanks
rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sort of.

You can use frameworks like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to create an iPhone/Android app with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. PhoneGap will make requests to your server, so that can be implemented in whatever you want. If you want to use ASP.NET MVC, I suggest you return JSON data structures to your mobile app.

You're probably better off writing a `Web API` than an MVC website for this, actually.